# hide keyboard for TextField with Edited Changed

Tags: ios, swift

It is real common issue with hiding keyboard in iOs app. To solve it i use

```
class myViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
```

and after that

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myTextField.delegate = self;
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
```

But it is not working this time because i have Editing Changed event of myTextField linked to one of my functions. So keyboard is not hiding.

How it can be solved in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `textFieldShouldReturn` do nothing special to hide keyboard. You have to hide it yourself.

`func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    return textField.resignFirstResponder()
}`

Answer (score 1):

> it is not working this time because i have Editing Changed event of myTextField linked to one of my functions

Normally what you have done should still work when return is clicked, I think. But perhaps there is some other factor I am missing. Perhaps related to something that the function does.

Here is an alternative way of dismissing the keyboard. Created with ctrl-click drag from text field's `Did End On Exit`

```
@IBAction func textFieldDoneEditing(sender: UITextField) {
    sender.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
```

//do not forget to call textfield delegate in viewdidload

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myTextField.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers - unfortunately they did not solve my problem.

I tried `-resignFirstResponder` with no success until i added return button to keyboard. Now after pressing it, keyboard hides.